# Revert from pnpm to npm

Tags: npm, pnpm

I just realized I won't be able to use pnpm in a project, due to compatibility issues with other tools. Is there a way to cleanly switch back to npm, which is my default package manager?
What would be your approach? I'm trying to avoid reverting back to a previous push.

Thank you!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This should be pretty easy:

- Delete `node_modules`
- Delete `pnpm_lock.yaml` (this will be replaced by `package-lock.json`)
- Replace all `pnpm` calls to `npm` in `package.json`

Now you can run `npm install`.
Tadaa, welcome back to npm.